# Guitar Pick-up issue

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, pick-ups, electronics

I've just bought a second hand ESP'81 humbucker pickup and have stuck it in a Les Paul project guitar of mine.

I am by no means an expert but I've used the wiring diagrams available to put it in there and everything seems to be soldered correctly.

On first plug-in the pickup sounded really thin, quiet and a little distorted in comparison to the stock neck pup I already had in the guitar.

I've just run a voltmeter over the '81 and i got a reading of 58.9ohms which seems like an insane amount of resistance.

Could this be the reason it sounds so weak? Do you have any suggestions for making the pup sing?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the Wikipedia page for this item, the output impedance is rated at 10 k ohms.  However, you cannot measure output impedance by sticking an ohmmeter across the leads.
  Simple things to check:   is the full 9V showing on the battery output?  When you turn up the gain & pluck strongly , what is the output voltage? -- Wiki says it's rated around 4.5 V peak,  3 V rms.  Make sure your voltmeter is high enough impedance not to pull down the output.